# Can I retrieve a frame i delete by drag and drop in dopesheet?

Tags: grease-pencil

I moved a keyframe and dropped it on a existing drawing in the dope sheet.

Now I can't find a way to get it back.

Is the stroke stored somewhere I can retrieve it live in Toonboom?

Comment: Did you undo (Ctrl+Z) it? Almost everything in Blender can be undone.

Comment: Hi, yes I can CTRL+Z to get it back if I do it right after the mistake, but what i am looking for if a way to retrieve a frame that was erased by mistake by a drag and drop. Maybe it's impossible and i have to be extra carful